# Empty Application on Xcode instead of other code generated templates

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to create an application on Xcode from Empty application on Xcode from scratch, I think is a nice way to learn more what is going on behind the scenes...

did anybody try this already? recommend any specific tutorial?

the ones I found on the internet are pretty basic or using other templates which really abstracts a lot of cool code I would like to get to know better.

I'm using XCode 4.3.2

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning iOS 5 Development by David Mark, Jack Nutting, and Jeff LaMarche covers how to do this in depth. I would recommend checking it out if you haven't done so yet.